# Liferay 7.0 Modify Navigation Menu for Certain pages

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have a Liferay portal set up for site1.com, I'd like to have a navigation menu for site1.com, and a different menu for any pages under site1.com/mypage.

Bare minimum, would be that all pages under site1.com index the whole site, but all pages under site1.com/mypage only index pages under site1.com/mypage

I've experimented with configuring the Navigation Menu, but I can't seem to get the menu I want on site1.com/mypage, without destroying the menu at site1.com.

My thought is that I should replicate the navigation menu item, call it Navigation Menu-MyPage, and include that at the top of all the site1.com/mypage pages. Is that something that can be done?

I'm new to liferay and not sure where on the file system the Navigation Menu resides (maybe just in the DB?) or how I can copy/rename it.

Or are Application Display Templates the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation Menu is a built-in portlet that is included on every page by the theme. As you largely specify "Certain Pages", the criteria for your pages could be the use of a common theme: You can build a theme that simply embeds a different Navigation Menu, one that you create by yourself, on each page. Then select this theme for the site you want to use the modified version on.

Comment: This was the direction I ended up going.